# Validar carga de imagen en PHP

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente código (Solo es ejemplo que ando replicando), al parece siempre se va por FALSE y me muestra el "echo "No se valió";", ya acomode la lógica de varias manera pero nunca se va por el TRUE ¿Alguien puede ayudarme?
Cabe menciona que subo un imagen por formulario en input tipo FILE, validando que sea dentro del tamaño y tipo que solicito en el código

```
    $permitidos = array("image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png");
    $limite_kb = 16384;
    if(in_array($_FILES['imagenTicket']['type'], $permitidos) && $_FILES['imagenTicket']['size'] <= $limite_kb * 1024) {
        echo "Se valio";
    } else {
        echo "No se valio";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Me funciono de la siguiente manera, con uso de in_array(); y jugando con la posición de los valores dentro del arreglo

```
    $permitidos = array("image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png");
    $limite_kb = 16384;
    $tipo = $_FILES['imagenTicket']['type'];
    $tamano = $_FILES['imagenTicket']['size'];
    if(in_array($tipo[0], $permitidos) && $tamano[0] <= $limite_kb * 1024) {
        echo "Se valio";
    } else {
        echo "No se valio";
    }
```